# Android Studio can't find class android.view.GhostView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I find into the class `android.transition.ChangeTransform` a reference to the `android.view.GhostView` class. But Android Studio can't find it and I can't use it.

[image: import error]

The source file for `GhostView` exist and can be open with 'search everywhere'. So I don't understand why I can't reference this class from my code... It's a simple public class!

[image]

Do Google hide some classes voluntary? Can I do something about it?

Some search results:

- [Code source on google source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/GhostView.java)
- [Code source on Github](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/nougat-release/core/java/android/view/GhostView.java)

Comment: Notice `@hide` in javadoc. It means this is part of the platform but not public API. Don't use it directly.

Comment: @EugenPechanec ho right... I didn't pay attention to this annotation. This is not cool.

Comment: Why the `w` is written as `v` on the docs

Comment: @AhmedHegazy it's because of the font size and italic style.